# Know which Form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have eight Forms in a page (Form0, Form1, Form2 and so on). When a form is submitted, data is handed by JS and send to ReassignPreg.php, which search data in DB and send it back with json. Then the proper divs on the page are updated.

The code below **is doing its job**. But I have eigh copies of almost the same code, one for each Form (I only copy two of them for brevity). Newbie and amateur as I am, I wander which would be **the way for synthesize this code** (get Form name, and then pass that to only one function).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Form0").submit(function(){
    var cadena = $(this).serialize();
    $.get('ReassignPreg.php?cadena='+cadena, function(row2){
      var text = row2;
      var obj = JSON.parse(text);
      var imagen='<img src="../ImageFolder/'+obj.File+'.png" width="530" />'

      $("#PregBox00").html(imagen)
      $("#PregBox01").html(obj.Clase)
      $("#PregBox02").html(obj.Dificultad)
      $("#PregBox03").html(obj.Tipo)
    });
  return false;
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Form1").submit(function(){
    var cadena = $(this).serialize();
    $.get('ReassignPreg.php?cadena='+cadena, function(row2){
      var text = row2;
      var obj = JSON.parse(text);
      var imagen='<img src="../ImageFolder/'+obj.File+'.png" width="530" />'

      $("#PregBox10").html(imagen)
      $("#PregBox11").html(obj.Clase)
      $("#PregBox12").html(obj.Dificultad)
      $("#PregBox13").html(obj.Tipo)
    });
  return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can have hidden filed with same form name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more modularity helps a lot

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=Form]").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var _form  = this.id.slice(-1); // 0, 1, etc
        var cadena = $(this).serialize() + '&form=' + _form;

        $.get('ReassignPreg.php?cadena=' + cadena, function (row) {
            var image = $('<img />', {
                src   : "../ImageFolder/" + row.File + ".png", 
                width : 530
            });

            $("#PregBox"+_form+"0").html(image);
            $("#PregBox"+_form+"1").html(row.Clase);
            $("#PregBox"+_form+"2").html(row.Dificultad);
            $("#PregBox"+_form+"3").html(row.Tipo);
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

now you'll have a `form` key on the server containing the number of the form, for instance in PHP you'd get that with `$_GET['form']` etc.

Comment: Thanks! So many answers in minutes, you guys are great. I'll try adeneo option first. Thank you!

Comment: And just for completeness, need to replace adeneo code: $("#PregBox"+_form+"1").html(obj.Clase); by $("#PregBox"+_form+"1").html(row.Clase); and so

Comment: @user1726522 - That's right, I forgot to change those, edited now, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you could add an hidden field to each form with an ID/name and use that to identify the form submitting

Answer (score 0):

You may need to assing classes to your `PregBox` elements and then target them accordingly to the form's ID.

```
  $('form').submit(function(){ // listen to all form submissions.
    var formID = $(this).prop('id'); // get the form ID here and do what you like with it.
    var cadena = $(this).serialize();
    $.get('ReassignPreg.php?cadena='+cadena, function(row2){
      var text = row2;
      var obj = JSON.parse(text);
      var imagen='<img src="../ImageFolder/'+obj.File+'.png" width="530" />'

      $("#PregBox00").html(imagen)
      $("#PregBox01").html(obj.Clase)
      $("#PregBox02").html(obj.Dificultad)
      $("#PregBox03").html(obj.Tipo)
    });
  return false;
  });
```